# custom grunt task naming convention

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, gruntjs

Is there any convention regarding naming custom grunt tasks that include more than one word? For example: [grunt-json-schema](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-json-schema) grunt plugin has [`json_schema` task](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-json-schema/blob/master/tasks/json_schema.js). One name includes dashes (`-`), the other includes underscores (`_`).

Obviously, dashed-name can't be used as a JavaScript object key:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    json-schema: { // WON'T work
```

they have to be enclosed in quotes:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    'json-schema': { // will work
```

I checked all official plugins (`grunt-contrib-*`), but they all consist of only one word. The motivation foor this question is simple: I just want to follow conventions.

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:**  Plugin/custom task names do not have to correlate to a specific config object name.

The Grunt.js api allows access to the config object using the [method](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config) `grunt.config`.  Tasks & Plugins have access to the entire object, not just the sub object correlating to the name.

For example, I could create a task called `foo` that accesses the config from `bar`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    bar: {
        baz: true
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('foo', 'example custom task', function () {
    var config = grunt.config('bar');
    grunt.log.ok(config);
});
```

**Best practice:** Plugin developers should name the key for their config object similar to the plugin name itself.  This helps mitigate conflicts with other plugins who could reference similar.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    foo: {
        baz: true
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('foo', 'example custom task', function () {
    var config = grunt.config('foo');
    grunt.log.ok(config);
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about naming convention.

Comment: It answers the question based on the context provided.  If you're looking for a literal answer re: naming convention, the answer is that Grunt reserves the `contrib-*` convention for their own plugins (`grunt-contrib-copy`), aside from that, a plugin author is free to name however they wish.

Answer (score -1):

I think the general convention is to use `camelCase` for tasks that consist of multiple words.